# JQuery click event, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following scenario.

I have a index.php page with the following JQuery code included

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#sIMG img').click(function() {
        var currentSRC = jQuery(this).attr('src');
        var altSRC = jQuery(this).attr('title');
        var imgID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        var cat = jQuery(this).attr('name');


        /*Fade, Callback, swap the alt and src, fade in */
        jQuery('#main').fadeOut('fast',function() {
            jQuery('#main').load("detail.php?id="+imgID+"&category="+cat);
            jQuery('#main').fadeIn('fast');

         });
    });
});
```

Now I have two div tags called #main and #right in the index.php page. When I click on a menu item right changes to a bunch of images, if I click on one of those images the above code should take effect and load into the main div, but it's just not working. the images are located within a div called sIMG. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are the images that are loaded in on the right (after clicking a parent image on the right) inserted via javascript or are they just hidden with css when the page loads?

Comment: Do you use a JS debugger? Check Firebug for any error messages.

Comment: Kindly elaborate on "just not working". Does it run at all? What happens when you stick `alert` all over the place?

Comment: If the images are dynamically loaded, you'll have to change it to: `jQuery('#sIMG img').live('click', function(){`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using **[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)**

```
jQuery('#sIMG img').live("click",function(){
});
```

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handlers.

```
jQuery('#sIMG img').on("click",function(){
});
```

Comment: As off jQuery 1.7 you should use .on() instead of live().

Comment: In 2017 using 3.0 live is deprecated, https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-on-quot-ready-quot-fn-removed

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're doing is setting "click" on the array that is return there. Try this:

```
jQuery('#sIMG img').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).click(function() {

    });
});
```

Comment: Is there any need to bind event handler like this to a jquery object?

Comment: Why would I have to use .live in order to get this work ? Is it because i may have duplicated ids as someone mentioned in this page? I changed the ids to ensure it was unique but I still had the same problem. Using .live worked, but I want to know why this happened?

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons that the jquery click don't work is that you have dupplicates id's in the form.